# Laravel FFmpeg error Call to undefined method FFMpeg\FFMpeg::fromDisk()

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, undefined, thumbnails

I'm using laravel ffmpeg to create a thumnail fot the video, but when i run the code, it return me

```
Call to undefined method FFMpeg\FFMpeg::fromDisk()
```

I don't know what happen to this error, i'm follow the instruction in github.
here is my code.

```
use FFMpeg\FFMpeg;
use FFMpeg\FFProbe;

$thumbnail_name =  md5($request->video_name).'_thumbnail.jpg';
$thumbnail_path = '/assets/' . $request->video_name;
FFMpeg::fromDisk('videos')
        ->open($export_as)
        ->getFrameFromSeconds(10)
        ->export()
        ->toDisk('thumnails')
        ->save($thumbnail_path);
```

i tried the `fromFilesystem` method, but it is not working, i also change the value in `fromDisk()` to `public/assets` even from c drive like `C:\xampp\htdocs\vidpuz\public\assets` but also not working, it keep return undefined method error.

Comment: there is no fromDisk method anywhere in the source code.

Comment: Are you using this package https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg

Comment: @RabahG then what should do?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
use Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpeg;
```

but you are using:

```
use FFMpeg\FFMpeg;
```

So you are not using the Laravel package but FFMpeg directly...

If you installed the package correctly.  You can even omit the `use Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpeg;` and use the facade directly.